# Netbeans Android emulator not running program

Tags: java, android, android-activity, netbeans, emulation

I am trying to run a very simple Hello World program on an emulator in the Netbeans Android IDE. The code compiles, the emulator launches (for android 4.0.3), but the Hello World app isn't on the phone. Am I missing something simple or is something wrong? Code below:

```
package com.test.helloworld;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class helloworld extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        TextView text1 = new TextView(this);
        text1.setText(“Hello World”);
        setContentView(text1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You aren't getting the textview correctly. You need to do something like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourcustomid);
        text1.setText(“Hello World”);
    }
```

This line here `TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourcustomid);` is how to get the id of the layout you created for your activity (which should be in main.xml), which might look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/yourcustomid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</RelativeLayout>
```